# How to get promoted page posts using FB api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am able to get all the page posts that can be promoted via the endpoint given at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/campaigns/objectives#connection_objects

eg query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/[PAGE-ID]/promotable_posts?fields=id&is_published=true&access_token=[TOKEN]
```

but how do I get all the posts that are already promoted? I am unable to find anything on the FB API docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this as there is no association between a post and an ad.

The easiest way to do this would likely be to request all creatives for an account, along with their object_story_id:

```
/<VERSION>/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives?fields=object_story_id
```

And then request all ads within the account along with creative and reference whether there is a match:

```
/<VERSION>/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/ads?fields=id,creative
```

Comment: I am able to fetch some data but can you please explain a bit more? I am trying to fetch comments from all the promoted posts, so does ```/<VERSION>/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/ads?fields=id,creative``` contains all the promoted posts? what do you mean by referencing for a match?

Comment: and I think its ```/<VERSION>/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives?fields=object_story_id``` and not ```/<VERSION>/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/creatives?fields=object_story_id```